# Integrating a token exchange in a project

Tags: erc-20, uniswap

I have a project where users can buy items with various ERC20 tokens but I want to provide an exchange for them so that they don't have to go to the other site and exchange them. So lets say that ITEM A costs x amount of TOKEN A but the buyer only has TOKEN B. What I want to do is let the buyer buy items in any currency but for a given exchange rate.

Is that possible to do with Uniswap and how would I integrate Uniswap into my smart contract that currently does just a simple transfer from one account to another. I've gone through bunch of tutorials but none of them show how to properly integrate Uniswap.

Answer (score 0):

Uniswap can do that, but only if token B is liquidity.

Integrating Uniswap is simple, and there are many things you can do using the Route contract, such as swap and add liquidity.

Another option is to deploy a set of Uniswap yourself, which can be cumbersome.

Comment: Do you maybe have some projects for reference. I am not entirely sure how would I integrate it. And regarding the liquidity, what if that token is already in the liquidity pool? Would I still need to provide the liquidity?

Comment: If you already have liquidity, you don't have to provide liquidity,

Comment: You should go to the Uniswap documentation, it goes into great detail